# How do I chat with another user on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, chat, stack-overflow

Sometimes I find old posts. I'd like to call a users attention to something new, or just ask for a followup.  How can I invite a user to chat?

I've clicked on the chat link and I can create a room, but I'm unable to invite a particular user.

Comment: when you see the chat link near the comments and press it, it will automatically create the room and invite the user, weather he accepts it or not is a different question. I guess the best way using the current features of this site would be if you @name this user on some post he made with a link to a room you've created.

Comment: ^Sounds like the answer

Comment: You can't invite a particular user to chat. You can only post a link in the comments of a question with a link to a chat room, or invite them _if they have been in chat before_.

Comment: To the OP: you can create an account here on Meta too; it'll be linked if you use the same email address, *then* you can comment on the question here.

Answer (score 35):

I just tried to figure this out, and this process worked:

1. Go to 'chat'.
2. Create a new room.
3. Click on 'room'.
4. Click on 'control access'.
5. Click on 'add new user' beside "explicit write access' (or 'owner', but this supposedly works for people who have chatted before)
6. Type in the user name.
7. Click on the user name (after it pops up).
8. Click on 'invite this user to [your room name]' --or-- 'start new room with this user'

I did this multiple times (trying different settings, and then to step through it again to write all of this out), and on just one occasion I got a pop-up window with a confirmation that an invitation was sent.

Comment: @a-m: I followed these steps and find a similar way but quicker than yours. Visit the uesr's profile. Add the subdomain "chat" to the url. (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/users/... becomes http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/...). This will allow you to visit the user's chat profile. Now do step 8!

Comment: @musafar006 Add your own answer. your method is great +1 !!!!

Comment: @LuisSiquot The question is marked as duplicate. Can't add a new answer.

Comment: @musafar006 - Sadly your method didn't work for me.

Comment: @aparente001 why not?

Comment: @musafar006 - Sorry, I should have said, I get a "Page Not Found."

Comment: @aparente001 make sure you're using SO's subdomain. I am not sure whether stackexchange domain has a subdomain for chat.

Comment: Somehow four years in and this procedure is still precisely as ridiculously awkward. This really needs to be streamlined.

Comment: Yeah, everytime I want to invite a new user, i have to loose unwanted 20 min. This is insane.

Comment: I just asked a question about this because I can't find it still https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300357/why-is-creating-a-new-room-or-inviting-someone-to-a-private-change-made-needless

Comment: Worth noting that you can not chat with new users < 20 rep. So it is not possible to guide a new user who deleted their question